# Synthesis of tin(II) nitrate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, synthesis, carbon-family

I tried to prepare $\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$ using tin(II) chloride and nitric acid according to the reaction

$$\ce{SnCl2 + 2 HNO3 -> Sn(NO3)2 + 2 HCl},$$

but stannous chloride appears to be poorly soluble (turbid solution). What is the correct method to prepare $\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$?

Comment: SnCl2 is pretty well soluble. This reaction is no good for other reasons.

Comment: I stay away from all nitrates and cyanides, at all costs. I wanna stay legit in the eyes of everybody.

Comment: I don't think that $\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$ exists as a salt. You can evidently make it in solution by dissolving $\ce{Sn(OH)2}$ in dilute nitric acid.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/make-tin-nitrate

Answer (score 3):

> Stannous Nitrate is obtained in white leaflets having the
> composition $\ce{Sn(NO3)2.20H2O}$ by cooling to $\pu{-20 °C}$. a solution of
> stannous oxide in nitric acid of density 1.2. It is also formed by the
> action of highly diluted nitric acid on the metal, some of the acid
> thus suffering maximum reduction to ammonia:
>
> $$\ce{4Sn + 10HNO3 -> 4Sn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + 3H2O}$$
>
> According to C. H. H. Walker, tin dissolves in nitric acid forming
> stannous and stannic nitrates, the relative proportion of these two
> salts produced depending on the temperature and the strength of the
> acid; moreover, the yellowish white precipitate which separates when
> the somewhat concentrated acid is employed is said to be a hydrated,
> ill-defined, stannic nitrate.

**Ref.**: http://tin.atomistry.com/stannous_nitrate.html

You can also check the post linked by Ivan.

Comment: All of this suggests that you get mixture of compounds every time, IMO there should be a better way.