# Sn + HNO3: When will the metastannic acid H2SnO3 appear?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I am dissolving tin in nitric acid.
What reactions will take place depending on the conentration of $\rm{HNO}_3$ and temperature?

Particularly, I am interested when the metastannic acid $\rm{H_2SnO_3}$ is likely to be produced, according to

$\rm{Sn + 4 HNO_3 → H_2O + H_2SnO_3 + 4 NO_2}$

P. S.
References to books or scientific articles are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common belief that tin dissolves in dilute nitric acid to produce tin(II) nitrate. The reactions are addressed in a [previous answer of mine.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67911/how-can-i-prepare-snno32/67938#67938) However, employing a more hot and concentrated nitric acid yields an unstable compound called hydrated stannic oxide also known as β-stannic acid. The compound also has a α-form which is later converted to β form. The relevant information can be found [here](http://tin.atomistry.com/stannic_acid_and_its_derivatives.html):

> [...]tin dissolves slowly, in very dilute nitric acid to produce
>   stannous nitrate (but) **when hot and more concentrated acid is
>   employed, is very unstable and quickly decomposes, yielding the form
>   of hydrated stannic oxide known as β-stannic acid.** Probably
>   α-stannic acid is first produced [...] which then passes into the
>   β-form. The product is, therefore, liable to contain both α- and
>   β-forms, and the **pure β-acid is obtained by dissolving this product
>   in sodium hydroxide solution, and then adding excess of concentrated
>   soda, which precipitates sodium p-stannate whilst the α-salt remains
>   in solution. Pure β-stannic acid, or β-metastannic acid, is then
>   obtained by decomposing the sodium salt with acid.** It is also formed
>   by the hydrolysis of its sodium salt at 60° C., and by boiling a
>   dilute solution of stannic chloride, with or without the addition of
>   nitric acid.[...]
>
> [...]Gelatinous, precipitated β-stannic acid has the empirical
>   composition $\ce{SnO2.4H2O}$, when air-dried $\ce{SnO2.2H2O}$, and
>   when dried in a vacuum, $\ce{SnO2.H2O}$; [...]

Comment: Thank you! What if I use **heated** dilute (say, 10%) nitric acid? Will stannous nitrate decompose in this case?

Comment: @bcp In the previous answer of mine, it is said that the reaction products will be a mixture of stannous nitrate and stannic nitrate but the proportion will vary according to temperature and concentration of acid. So, i suppose, hot solution of nitric acid will probably produce more amount of stannic nitrate.