# Decomposition reaction of tin(II) nitrate

Tags: experimental-chemistry

What are the products formed when $\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$ is subjected to high temperatures?

I searched over the internet but I didn't get any satisfactory answer.

Comment: I'd expect SnO2.

Comment: Pure anhydrous $Sn(NO_3)_2$ does not exist. Only $Sn(NO_3)_2·20H_2O$ exists, and it is a liquid at ordinary temperature (melting point : -20°C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No wonder you cannot find any literature on $\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$, because I don't think it exists in solid form. This is supported by the fact that I even can't find its CAS number online. This book (Ref.1) and relevant paper (Ref.2) support my suggestion, both of which state that:

> Attempts to prepare a covalently bound tin(II) nitrate, by the reaction of tin(IV) tetranitrate with anhydrous nitric oxide, have produced only a white solid solid of formula $\ce{SnN2O6}$, which gives a tin(IV) Mössbauer resonance ($\delta = \pu{0.29 mm\:s-1}$, $\Delta = \pu{0.96 mm\:s-1}$)...

Nonetheless, a study on thermal decomposition of metal nitrates (Ref.3) states that:

> Due to a back-donation of electronic cloud from the nitrate to an unfilled $\mathrm{d}$-orbital of transition and noble metals, their nitrates generally exhibited lower decomposition temperatures ($T_d \lt \pu{700 K}$) than those of the base metals ($\gt \pu{850 K}$).

They suggest those metal nitrates with lower decomposition temperatures decompose to corresponding oxides together with $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{O2}$. Thus, it is safe to assume that ***if $\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$ exists***, it would decompose as following reaction suggest:

$$\ce{2 Sn(NO3)2 (s) + heat -> 2 SnO (s) + 4 NO2 (g) + O2 (g)}$$

However, keep in mind that this is pure speculation.

**References:**

1. R. Greatrex, “Chapter 8: Mössbauer Spectroscopy,” In *Specialist Periodical Reports: Spectroscopic Properties of Inorganic and Organometallic Compounds, Volume 6*; N. N. Greenwood, Ed.; The Chemical Society Burlington House: London, United Kingdom, 1973, pp. 494-622.
2. P. G. Harrison, M. I. Khalil, N.Logan, “Concerning anhydrous tin(II) nitrate,” *Inorganic and Nuclear Chemistry Letters* **1972**, *8(6)*, 551-553 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-1650(72)80139-9).
3. Shanmugam Yuvaraj, Lin Fan-Yuan, Chang Tsong-Huei, Yeh Chuin-Tih, “Thermal Decomposition of Metal Nitrates in Air and Hydrogen Environments,” *J. Phys. Chem. B* **2003**, *107(4)*, 1044-1047 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jp026961c).

Comment: [$\ce{Sn(NO3)2}$ definitely does exist but only in solution and is ill-defined.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67911/synthesis-of-tinii-nitrate). Moreover, it is written in [this paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1961/jr/jr9610001996): "The dilute solution of tin(II) nitrate is reasonably stable [...] Attempts to evaporate to crystallization result in decomposition, which may occasionally be violent. The decomposition produces tin(IV) oxide, and various nitrogen compounds, principally hydroxylamine and nitrous oxide."