# How to find number of moles of HNO3 behaving like acid in a redox reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

> In the reaction $(1)$, how to find the number of moles of $\ce{HNO3}$, which is behaving like acid?

The reaction is given as follows:

$$\ce{Sn + HNO3 -> Sn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + H2O} \tag1$$

To find number of moles of $\ce{HNO3}$ behaving like acid, I first balanced the reaction using oxidation number method which gave me:

$$\ce{4Sn + 10HNO3 -> 4Sn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + 3H2O}$$

But I could not proceed any further. I am unable to find any hint. How should we proceed to reach the answer? Answer mentioned in book is 9.  This is a question from chapter "Redox Reactions".

Comment: Try splitting into half-equations to find how many moles of HNO3 are accepting electron pairs and acting as Lewis acids.

Comment: I also tried Half reaction method, but I couldn't observe the solution.

Comment: @Sahil in the future, enclose chemical equations and formulae in `$\ce{}$` : it typesets chemistry automatically.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/67911/how-can-i-prepare-snno32/67938#67938 ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/103349/sn-hno3-when-will-the-metastannic-acid-h2sno3-appear ... https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/make-tin-nitrate

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! When asking problem statements, could you try to conform to this [template](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4808/a-concise-template-for-homework-questions)? You seem to be someone who would stick through SE for an extended period of time and we would be glad to keep it that way.

Answer (score 2):

It is always easy to balance redox equations by considering two half reactions. The equation to be balanced is:

$$\ce{Sn + HNO3 -> Sn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + H2O}$$

Thus, the two relevant half reactions to this redox equation are:
$$\ce{Sn (s) -> Sn^2+ (aq)} \\
\ce{NO3- (aq) -> NH4+ (aq)}$$

First balance elements other than $\ce{O}$ and $\ce{H}$. In this case they are $\ce{Sn}$ in first equation and $\ce{N}$ in second equation. Then, balance $\ce{O}$ and $\ce{H}$ in both equations with water and $\ce{H+}$, respectively. This is because the reaction is in aqueous acidic medium:

$$\ce{ Sn (s)  -> Sn^2+ (aq)}\\
\ce{NO3- (aq) + 10 H+ (aq) -> NH4+ (aq) + 3 H2O (l)}$$

Finally, balance the positive charges by electrons so that each equation has no net charges:
$$\ce{ Sn (s)  -> Sn^2+ (aq) + 2e-} \tag1$$
$$\ce{NO3- (aq) + 10 H+ (aq) + 8 e- -> NH4+ (aq) + 3 H2O (l)} \tag2$$

These are your mass and charge balanced oxidation ($(1)$) and reduction ($(2)$) half-reactions. Now, you can add these two equations in order to cancel electrons. To do so add $4 \times (1) + (2)$:

$$\ce{ 4 Sn (s) + NO3- (aq) + 10 H+ (aq) -> 4 Sn^2+ (aq) + NH4+ (aq) + 3 H2O (l)} \tag3$$

This is your balanced ionic equation. As evidence, you need nine $\ce{NO3-}$ ions to balance as counter ions in right hand side, so you need to add $\ce{9NO3-}$ to both side to keep the mass and charge balance.:

$$\ce{ 4 Sn + NO3- + 10 H+ + 9 NO3- -> 4 Sn^2+ + NH4+ + 9 NO3- + 3 H2O} \tag4$$

When simplify, the equation $(4)$ would look like:

$$\ce{ 4 Sn +10 H+ + 10 NO3- -> 4 Sn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + 3 H2O} \tag5$$

Since $\ce{ +10 H+ + 10 NO3- = 10 HNO3}$, your complete balance equation is:

$$\ce{ 4 Sn +10 HNO3 -> 4 Sn(NO3)2 + NH4NO3 + 3 H2O}\tag5$$

Therefore, your answer is correct. Answer in your textbook must be a misprint or accidently for got that one $\ce{HNO3}$ is needed to be reduced. Other $\ce{9NO3-}$ is to balance the products (as counter ions). All $\ce{10H+}$ ions needed to complete the redox reaction.

Answer (score -2):

While balancing,
$$\ce{Sn + HNO_{3} \longrightarrow Sn(NO_{3})_{2} + NH_{4}NO_{3} + H_{2}O}$$

first balance oxidising agent and reducing agent only, we will get $\ce{4Sn}$ and $\ce{1HNO_{3}}$ , after balancing them, write number of **extra** moles of acid obtained while balancing other atoms. That will give us the answer.